# why my background working thread is blocking UI thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am working on an app, which uploads native contacts to server then get responses(JSON, a contact list that already installed the app). When native contacts are large enough, server response will be slow and unstable. And user cannot do other things. so I put network request into background thread. every time I will upload 100 contacts, do some tasks , then next 100 contacts until loop finish.

But in running, the result is not as expected. background thread is running, it keeps to request server. UI thread is blocked, I still cannot do anything.

is this cause a long loop in background thread? Although I have 2 thread, but they will compete CPU resources(test device is iPod, 1 core. And I think this may not related core numbers)?

Could anyone tell me hints on how to handle this kind of scenario? Thanks in advance!

Update:

I have found the root cause. A global variable in App delegate is set to wrong value, therefore UI behavior is weird. I found this by comment all network request method. So this problem is not related with multiple threading. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @CodaFi
No. I use NSOperationQueue in app delegate. every request for 100 contacts are throw into the queue.

Comment: I guess the better question is: Can you use GCD?  Or do you need to target iOS 3.x?

Comment: @CodaFi Thx. Yes I will have a try. hope this issue can solved too. :) I think I must missed some key point in multithreading(in learning...), and afraid of same issue happen after applying GCD.

Comment: Are you sure that you're only updating data model in the background (and not fiddling with UI in any way)?

Comment: @rokjarc Yes.I have double checked codes. no ui related in background. Finally I found the root cause. it is not related with multiple thread. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think there needs to be some clarification as to how you are performing the network operations.

1st, NSOperatiomQueue deals with NSOperations, so you are presumably wrapping your network code in an NSOperation subclass.

2nd, are you using NSURLConnections for your networking code?

3rd, is the blocking part the NSURLConnection or you delegate callback for NSURLConnection?

1 thing to note is that plain ol' NSURLConnections are implemented under the hood multithreaded.  The object is placed into your main threads run loop by default (when run from the main thread), but the object is just a wrapper that handles callbacks to the delegate from the lower level networking code (BSD sockets) which happens on another thread.

You really shouldn't be able to block your UI with NSURLConnections on the main thread, unless A) you are blocking the thread with expensive code in the delegate callback methods or B) you are overwhelming your run loop with too many simultaneous URL connections (which is where NSOperationQueue's setMaxConcurrentOperationsCount: comes into play)

Comment: Thx. My answers:1st, yes, I am using NSInvocationOperation to wrap network request method. 2nd/3rd, no, I use a SDK method to request server, it is sync call.

Comment: I am just wondering whether Appdelegate can be accessed in multiple thread. server request method is in app delegate, and it will called in background thread. I will have a try by moving it elsewhere.